# electronize build does not produce output in \bin\desktop folder

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, electron, electron.net

I try to build my electron app using the command "electronize build /target win" but no output is produced in the \bin\desktop folder

I tried to use different build targets. But only output is produced in obj/desktop. There is no Electron executable in that folder

The output of electronize build is:

```
Build Electron Application...
Build ASP.NET Core App for win-x64...
Executing dotnet publish in this directory: D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win
Build ASP.NET Core App for win-x64 under Release-Configuration...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator>dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --output "D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0-preview-19377-01+dd8019d9e for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
  Restore completed in 51.27 ms for D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\QueryCreator\QueryCreator.csproj.
  Restore completed in 32.03 ms for D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Orm\Orm\Orm.csproj.
  Restore completed in 49.1 ms for D:\Source\Base\Support\Services\BillableClient\BillableClient\BillableClient.csproj.
  Restore completed in 55.58 ms for D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Helpers\Helpers\Helpers.csproj.
  Restore completed in 55.27 ms for D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\MicroGet\MicroGet\MicroGet.csproj.
  Restore completed in 55.29 ms for D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Contracts\Contracts\Contracts.csproj.
  Restore completed in 53.16 ms for D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\QueryCreator\QueryCreator.csproj.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  Helpers -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Helpers\Helpers\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\Buckaroo.Common.Helpers.dll
  Helpers -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
  MicroGet -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\MicroGet\MicroGet\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\Buckaroo.Common.MicroGet.dll
  MicroGet -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
  Helpers -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Helpers\Helpers\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Buckaroo.Common.Helpers.dll
  Orm -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Orm\Orm\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\Buckaroo.Common.Orm.dll
  Orm -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
  Contracts -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Contracts\Contracts\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\Buckaroo.Common.Contracts.dll
  Orm -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Orm\Orm\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Buckaroo.Common.Orm.dll
  Contracts -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
  MicroGet -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\MicroGet\MicroGet\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Buckaroo.Common.MicroGet.dll
  Contracts -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Common\Contracts\Contracts\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Buckaroo.Common.Contracts.dll
  BillableClient -> D:\Source\Base\Support\Services\BillableClient\BillableClient\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\win-x64\Buckaroo.Services.BillableClient.dll
  BillableClient -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
  QueryCreator -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\QueryCreator\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\QueryCreator.dll
  QueryCreator -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\QueryCreator\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.0\win-x64\QueryCreator.Views.dll
  QueryCreator -> D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator>
Start npm install...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>npm install --production
added 67 packages from 64 contributors and audited 359 packages in 2.817s
found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>
Start npm install electron-builder...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>npm install electron-builder --global
C:\Users\m.bergman\AppData\Roaming\npm\electron-builder -> C:\Users\m.bergman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\cli.js
C:\Users\m.bergman\AppData\Roaming\npm\install-app-deps -> C:\Users\m.bergman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\install-app-deps.js
+ electron-builder@21.2.0
updated 1 package in 6.259s
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>
ElectronHostHook handling started...
Build Electron Desktop Application...
Executing electron magic in this directory: D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\bin\desktop
Create electron-builder configuration file...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>node build-helper.js
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>
Package Electron App for Platform win...
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>electron-builder . --config=./bin/electron-builder.json --win --x64 -c.electronVersion=5.0.8
  ÔÇó electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=10.0.17134
  ÔÇó loaded configuration  file=D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win\bin\electron-builder.json
  ÔÇó packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=5.0.8 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  ÔÇó default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set
  ÔÇó building        target=nsis file=dist\electron.net.host Setup 1.0.2.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  ÔÇó building block map  blockMapFile=dist\electron.net.host Setup 1.0.2.exe.blockmap
D:\Source\Tools\QueryCreator\obj\desktop\win>
... done
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue now bu there is no answer :(